# How to create an size effect on the action bar Android?

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar

I would like to reproduce size effect offered by google music on the action bar :

[image: Action Bar Google Music]

**Does someone has an idea to reproduce it?**

Comment: Go for action bar/sherlock library

Comment: Size effect is the shadow under the action bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution :**

1) Download this drawble and placing in `drawable-xhdpi` folder :

[image: ab_background]

2) And change background of the action bar :

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_background));
```